# Cron job isn't working

Tags: server, scripts, cron

I have an sh file called `m.sh` with the contents:

```
echo "Cleaning memory"
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo ""
free -m

echo ""

ps cax | grep java > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "== Server is already running =="
else
  sh a.sh
  echo "========== STARTING THE SERVER =========="
fi
```

When I run it with `sh m.sh` it works perfectly. But I need it to run every 5 minutes, so I am using cron jobs. It needs to work as root/sudo so I did `sudo -s`, then `crontab -e` and wrote this in the file:

```
0,4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54 * * * * /bin/sh /home/<username>/m.sh
```

I had done some research, and I learned that the cron has different paths than the user, that is why I used those absolute paths, to make sure.

The cron job wasn't running the script every 5 minutes, as it was supposed to.

I also added

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "Testing123"
```

to test if cron was working at all, and nothing came up in the console.

How can I make the cron run the script every 5 minutes? I did research online, and tried the solutions, but couldn't make it to work for me. I did `service cron start` and it said it was already running. I also restarted the service. The permissions are set correctly, I gave all users read, write, and execute permissions just to make sure (I know the permissions are correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your test script -- crontab jobs are not connected to a physical console, so don't expect any output. Try

```
* * * * * /bin/touch /tmp/foo
```

... and see whether the `/tmp/foo` file gets updated. It should.

To get a script running every five minutes, there is a shortcut:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /whatever/script/blah.sh
```

Furthermore, I would edit your script such that it logs its activity. For example,

```
LOGFILE=/var/log/leoncleaner.log
# ...
echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` Starting server >> $LOGFILE
```

Alternatively, you can redirect the output from the crontab file directly:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /whatever/script/blah.sh >> /var/log/leoncleaner.log
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got it figured out now. I don't know what the problem was before, maybe it was working but I didn't know it. Also, is there a way to make it write the output in the console?

Comment: Sort of. Redirect the output of the script to a log file (`logfile.name`). Then open a console and type `tail -f logfile.name`. It will read the file `logfile.name` and update the output when the file grows.

Comment: Oh, wait, it isn't fixed. I stopped the server, and waited for the cron job to restart it. In the logs I could see that when it noticed the server had stopped, it said "Starting the server", but it actually didn't. But when I run that script myself, and it said "Starting the server", it did. The script is working apparently, because it works when I run it, but only half works when it is run by cron

Comment: OK, but that is another issue. Add the full path to a.sh.

Comment: I changed `sh a.sh` with `sh /home/<username>/a.sh` but the exact thing still happens

Comment: k, I found the problem. `a.sh` was running correctly, but there was a mistake in one of the paths inside `a.sh`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `echo PATH=$PATH > path.tmp`.  Then add the contents of path.tmp to the beginning of your script.  This will provide the same path you have interactively to the script.

You may want to add a bang path to beginning of your scrript.  Something like `#!/bin/bash`  should work.

Also make sure your script is executable.  Run the command `chmod +x m.sh`.  Then test your script can be run as `./m.sh`.

Output of the script should be mailed to the user id of the crontab it is running.   In the case of root, ensure you have an alias to a user id you are monitoring for mail in `/etc/aliases`.  Generally, you don't want output from cron scripts unless something fails.  Redirect output to a log if you need it.